# Android on location changed

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I'm having trouble to understand how the `map.setmylocationenabled(true)` actualy gets my location every time I move. And my question is: Is there a way to extract longitude and latitude from `map.setmylocationenabled(true)`?

The code that shows my location on the map and updates it every time I move.

```
map.setmylocationenabled(true)
```

Comment: link will help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720614/what-is-firebase-and-how-to-use-it-in-android

Comment: I'm not planning to use firebase, and I don't see how that post can help my situation

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the guide about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). You should use `requestLocationUpdates()` to ask for updates. And in `onLocationChanged()` call `getLastKnownLocation()` to obtain a Location object on which you can call `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()`. ([getLatitude doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getLatitude()))